# Can Spring EL (SpEL) be configured to ignore null objects in the middle of an expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

If I have the expression: obj1.obj2.obj3

And obj2 is null, then expression fails with an exception.  Is there any way to configure SpEL to just return null?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use safe navigation operator that is `?.` (in your example that'd be `obj1?.obj2?.obj3`) to avoid nasty `NullPointerException` while navigating graph of beans.

You can find detailed explanation and some examples in chapter **6.5.15 Safe Navigation operator** of [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Not sure how I missed that when I was reading the reference :/